# SSRS Indent Toggle Icon

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, indentation, togglebutton, ssrs-grouping

I'm using Visual Studio to create reports. Very new to this. I'm trying to indent the plus/minus toggle button with the grouping so it'll be in line with the group text.  I'm using the following in the Left Padding Expression but it isn't working (=CStr(2 + (Level()*10)) + "pt").  Any suggestions? Thanks.

PS - I have no reputation points so I can't post images.

Comment: If you put static values for the padding ("20 pt") does it work?

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks. I don't know what I was doing before that wasn't allowing this.

Comment: If the static value worked, then there must have been something not right about the expression you were using.  Unfortunately I don't see what it is, so you'd just have to experiment with it until you got it right.

Comment: My settings were all screwed. When I increase my padding incrementally and make sure there's no left indent then I get what I'm looking for.

Comment: This expression should work.  Is this an online report you are creating?